# 2017 AngularJS 1.0 vs Google AdSense

Tags: angularjs, adsense

I am trying to use **Google AdSense** in my web application, created with **Angular JS 1.0** framework. Because the *crawler* and the *single-page-app technology* I can not get the acknowledge, so my website stays **denied** by AdSense. 
There are several opinions and suggestions from 2013-2015, I have tried them already without success. I have read the followings: backend-node.js service for crawler, prerender.io, etc... but these seems quite difficult, I think there should be an easier way.
Please, help me if you can, how can I solve this. I really appreciate it! Please write *only working* and tested ideas/solutions, there are many useless/deprecated advices on the web.
Thank you!

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Comment: We "solved" it with prerender.io, and created a new sub-website with a lot of text. Google approved it after 20 tries...